# QML ListView Delegates z-order are always on top of everything else

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML ListView with a custom widget (I call it PayloadOdometerRecord) as a delegate.    This PayloadOdometerRecord contains a couple of other custom widgets (TextBox) that when clicked will change state and display a keyboard for user input.

The ListView works correctly until the user clicks one of these TextBox widgets to display the keyboard.  The keyboard gets clipped by all of the delegates below the delegate that is displaying the keyboard.

When using this TextBox widget in a non-ListView, it works correctly...the keyboard is fully visible.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  My goal is to have a full-screen keyboard that shows up and is not covered by any other components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you show some code? What is the parent of your keyboard component?
Z works only between siblings. The keyboard should be a child of the root element and have a higher z value than the other children of root to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea...I made a property alias to the keyboard's parent and I set that to the root element in my qml.

Answer (score 0):

If there are other components in front of the keyboard, you can try to set the keyboards `z`-property to a large value (e.g. 1000) [→ Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-item.html#z-prop)